# Linking a Fortran program with an arbitrary binary file

Tags: windows, gcc, fortran, gfortran, fortran-iso-c-binding

I would like to link a Fortran program with an arbitrary binary file. I am using gfortran, and I found [here](https://balau82.wordpress.com/2012/02/19/linking-a-binary-blob-with-gcc/) that the same task is easy with gcc using [objcopy](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/binutils/objcopy.html) from binutils.

However, I can't make it work with gfortran.

Here is a working trivial example with gcc

First, `build.c` to build the data file, containing only the binary representation of the number pi=3.14...

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    FILE *f;

    double x = M_PI;
    f = fopen("data.bin", "wb");
    fwrite(&x, sizeof x, 1, f);
    fclose(f);
    return 0;
}
```

Then `cbin.c`, to print the number.

```
# include <stdio.h>

extern double val;

int main() {
    printf("%lf\n", val);
    return 0;
}
```

Then, to build the executable, I do this

```
objcopy -I binary -O elf32-i386 -B i386 --redefine-sym _binary_data_bin_start=_val data.bin data.o
objdump -t data.o
gcc cbin.c data.o
```

Notice that the start of data is renamed to `_val`.

I tried the following with gfortran

```
program forbin
    implicit none
    double precision :: val
    common val
    print *, val
end program
```

Then

```
objcopy -I binary -O elf32-i386 -B i386 --redefine-sym _binary_data_bin_start=_val_ data.bin data.o
objdump -t data.o
gfortran forbin.f95 data.o
```

Now, the start of data is renamed to `_val_`, to follow gfortran naming convention. The compilation step works, but at execution the number 0 is printed instead of pi, so something went wrong. I'm not even sure the `common` is the right thing to do, and I wonder if there could be some confusion between address and value.
Also, I would be interested in array data, rather than a single scalar (I can do this in C too, using a pointer on val).

Any idea on what I should do to make this work ?

In case it's important, I'm working with gcc 4.9.1 from [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/files/Toolchains%20targetting%20Win32/Personal%20Builds/mingw-builds/4.9.1/threads-win32/dwarf/), on Windows 7, 32 bits. Initially, I'm doing this to build a DLL for use in Excel. I *could* do this in C, but I would prefer a pure Fortran approach if possible.

---

**edit**

Following suggestion from High Performance Mark and [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/fortran-iso-c-binding/info) from Stack Overflow, here is a solution for scalar data

```
module binmod
    use iso_c_binding, only: c_double
    real(c_double), bind(c) :: val
end module

program forbin
    use binmod
    implicit none
    print *, val
end program
```

And of course I use the C name `_val` instead of `_val_`.

However, when doing this with an array, I still don't see how to use the symbols from `data.o` to declare the array in Fortran. I could write the dimensions by hand, but it does not seem very robust (it would be easy to forget to update the Fortran code if I update the data).

Here is the output from `objdump -t data.o`

```
00000000 l    d  .data  00000000 .data
00000000 g       .data  00000000 _val
00000008 g       .data  00000000 _binary_data_bin_end
00000008 g       *ABS*  00000000 _binary_data_bin_size
```

The global `_binary_data_bin_end` is a marker of end of data, similar to `_binary_data_bin_start` that I renamed to `_val`, and `_binary_data_bin_size` is an "absolute" value. In C, it would be possible to print this latter value with

```
extern char binary_data_bin_size;
...
printf("%d\n", &binary_data_bin_size);
```

However, I don't even understand how a pointer can do the job here, even if I don't consider the warning from the compiler. It works, but I don't know how, nor how to adapt it to gfortran.

Comment: You should read about Fortran's *interoperability with C* features in your toolchain's documentation.  Manual name-mangling, like common blocks, belongs in the dustbin of history.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark Thank you for this valuable comment, it leads me to a partial solution. See edit

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut This is a very interesting question. May I ask where might one find the use for this technique? What kinds of software engineering problems does this tackle?

Comment: @deepak In my case, it's not absolutely mandatory: I'm using Fortran DLLs for use within Excel, and sometimes I need to link some data (nomenclatures are an obvious example, but also data for maps and precomputed tables). Usually, I format everything as Fortran source, but I thought it could be convenient to link directly the files. Now I think I was wrong, but I'm still interested in the answer though. There is also another option: using Windows resources. I'm not familiar with these, but I tried in C and it works.

Comment: @deepak The simplest is probably to leave everything within Excel, and use VBA to pass things to Fortran when needed (but it's quite awkward from the code perspective, and passing strings from VBA is not funny). Nevertheless, it was an interesting exercise. Another option, loading data from the original files, but it then needs many files in addition to the DLLs. There are many ways to solve my problem...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As mentioned in the a comment, you want to use the `iso_c_binding` intrinsic Fortran module to provide C interoperability features.

The following code/example is produced with GCC 4.9.2 on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu.

#### Scalar data

Consider the following Fortran:

```
module data
  use iso_c_binding
  implicit none
  real(kind=c_double), bind(C) :: val
end module

program fbin
  use data
  implicit none
   print *,val
end program
```

This uses a Fortran module containing the variable `var` which is compatible with the C type `double`.  The `bind(C)` attribute will cause the variable exposed in the object file to be unmangled (e.g. `var` with no underscoring).  Note the use of the module is necessary because you cannot apply the bind attribute in the main program scope (or at least GCC won't allow this, I haven't consulted the standard).

I used your code to produce data.bin, but for my system I had to modify the `objcopy` as follows:

```
objcopy -I binary -O elf64-x86-64 -B i386 --redefine-sym _binary_data_bin_start=val data.bin data.o
```

The changes are the bfdname to produce an object my system can consume and changing the symbol name to plain `val` to match what the Fortran compiler will expect.

The rest follows as your example:

```
% objdump -t data.o                                                                          

data.o:     file format elf64-little

SYMBOL TABLE:
0000000000000000 l    d  .data  0000000000000000 .data
0000000000000000 g       .data  0000000000000000 val
0000000000000008 g       .data  0000000000000000 _binary_data_bin_end
0000000000000008 g       *ABS*  0000000000000000 _binary_data_bin_size
```

and

```
% gfortran -o fbin fbin.f90 data.o
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.9.2/../../../../x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/bin/ld: Warning: alignment 1 of symbol `val' in data.o is smaller than 8 in /tmp/ccYcttlP.o
```

Note that this warning does not cause the program to fail, but will impact the performance of the program.  I'm not sure if you'll have alignment issues on your platform.  Finally:

```
% ./fbin 
   3.1415926535897931
```

Success.

#### Array data

Here is a modified build.c to produce a 1-d array of values for testing:

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    FILE *f;
    int i;

    double x; 
    f = fopen("data.bin", "wb");
    for (i=0; i<15; i++) {
      x = M_PI*i;
      fwrite(&(x), sizeof x, 1, f);
    }
    fclose(f);
    return 0;
}
```

This produces data.bin with 15 8-byte values from 0 to 14*M_PI.  The `data.o` is produced with the same command as in my scalar example.

Here is an example Fortran program that is hardcoded to load a rank 2 array with shape (3,5).

```
module data
  use iso_c_binding
  implicit none
  integer, parameter :: n = 3
  integer, parameter :: m = 5
  real(kind=c_double), target, bind(C) :: val
  real(kind=c_double), dimension(:,:), pointer :: array

contains

  subroutine init_fort_array()
    use iso_c_binding
    implicit none
    call c_f_pointer(c_loc(val), array, [n,m])
  end subroutine
end module

program forbin
  use data
  implicit none
  integer :: j
  call init_fort_array()
  print '(5(f8.5,2x))',(array(1:n,j), j=1,m)
end program
```

This is a little less straightforward and is perhaps not the only way to accomplish this, but it is the one that came to mind.  The module has a scalar value `val` and an array pointer.  A subroutine gets the address of val with `c_loc` and associates the Fortran pointer `array` with that address and using the given shape.  You just need to call that subroutine in your code and then `array` works as expected.

This array is hardcoded but you could use other data files (or a single data file with multiple symbols) to pack the array rank and dimensions into the data object and then change the Fortran to use a shape dependent on the actual data.

No example would be complete without output:

```
% ./fbin                          
 0.00000   9.42478  18.84956  28.27433  37.69911
 3.14159  12.56637  21.99115  31.41593  40.84070
 6.28319  15.70796  25.13274  34.55752  43.98230
```

Note that Fortran and C do not use the same array ordering.  C is row-major and Fortran is column major and you can see this in how my Fortran loop prints the data.

Comment: Thank you! I'm much interested by the array solution ;-) Regarding alignment, it may be possible to use the `--file-alignment` or `--section-alignment` options of [objcopy](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/binutils/objcopy.html), I didn't try.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut I have added an array example.  I also tried the alignment options you mention but the compiler warning persists for me.  Something to look at for sure, but the example works in any case.